# com.apple.launchd.peruser -> org.freedesktop.dbus-session error

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm getting the following error every 10 seconds in Console Messages. No idea where it comes from.

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[146]  (org.freedesktop.dbus-session[47150]) posix_spawn("/opt/local/bin/dbus-daemon", ...): No such file or directory
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[146]  (org.freedesktop.dbus-session[47150]) Exited with exit code: 1
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[146]  (org.freedesktop.dbus-session) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

I don't even have /opt/ (I used MacPorts *long* ago and I don't remember having had anything else in /opt/ since then). Any idea where to look for in debugging this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like launchd is trying to launch something which is no longer installed.

Check your `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, and `~/Library/LaunchAgents` folders for a file name starting with "`org.freedesktop.dbus`".  If you find one, delete it.

You can also use [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/) to configure launchd programs graphically.

Comment: To stop it from running without rebooting you should run `launchctl stop org.freedesktop.dbus-session` in this case.